# Comparing two dates from different format

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

How to compare this two dates from different format to check if they are equal

```
Date d1 = bean.fooDate; // >> from a post request
System.out.println(d1); // >> "Sat May 25 10:00:00 WET 2019"

Date d2 = fooEntity.getFooDate(); // >> from mysql database
System.out.println(d2); // >> "2019-05-25"
```

P.S i want just compare it as date not as datetime (no need to compare minutes & secondes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that your two dates have different format isn’t really accurate. A `Date` hasn’t got a format. What you see what you print the dates is the return values from their `toString` methods.

Rather your dates have got different *runtime types*. `d1` is an instance of `java.util.Date` and its `toString` method produced the format `Sat May 25 10:00:00 WET 2019`. `d2`in turn is an instance of `java.sql.Date`. It’s a subclass of `java.util.Date`, so can be assigned to a variable of this type. `java.sql.Date.toString()` produces the format `2019-05-25`. However, the subclass (inheritance) relationship is a hack that you shouldn’t rely on in code.

The inheritance hack is just one out of many design problems with those two classes, though. Fortunately a newer and more modern replacement exists for both. For `java.util.Date` the modern `Instant` class is the most directly corresponding type, but exactly which one to use depends on your more precise requirements. For `java.sql.Date` it’s simpler, use `LocalDate`. Both `Instant` and `LocalDate` are part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

So see if you can replace `bean.fooDate` by an `Instant` or other appropriate modern type from java.time. Similarly see if you can get `fooEntity.getFooDate()` to return a `LocalDate`. Hibernate should be happy to handle `LocalDate` rather than `Date` for you (unless your Hibernate version is very old).

In any case, Srinivasan Sekar is correct that you should convert whatever type you get from each to `LocalDate` to compare only the dates and not the hours, minutes and seconds. `LocalDate` is exactly that: a date without time of day.

Say that you get an `Instant` from `bean.fooDate`. Then the conversion is:

```
    LocalDate localDate1 = bean.fooDate.atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/El_Aaiun")).toLocalDate();
```

Be sure to specify an appropriate time zone.

If you cannot avoid an old-fashioned `Date`, the conversion in Srinivasan Sekar’s answer is correct:

```
    LocalDate localDate1 = bean.fooDate
            .toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/El_Aaiun"))
            .toLocalDate();
```

For the case of `fooEntity.getFooDate()`, if you can get a `LocalDate` as mentioned, you’re done. If you can get only a `Date`, first check whether the method is declared to return a `java.util.Date` or a `java.sql.Date`. It probably depends on the import used in the file where the method is declared. The case of a `java.sql.Date` is simple enough (though unfortunately not guaranteed to give the correct date always):

```
    LocalDate localDate2 = fooEntity.getFooDate().toLocalDate();
```

If the declared return type is `java.util.Date`, you may just add a cast to the above since it seems that the actually returned object is a `java.sql.Date`. It would be safer to test your assumption first, though:

```
    LocalDate localDate2;
    Date d2 = fooEntity.getFooDate();
    if (d2 instanceof java.sql.Date) {
        localDate2 = ((java.sql.Date) fooEntity.getFooDate()).toLocalDate();
    } else {
        localDate2 = d2.toInstant()
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/El_Aaiun"))
                .toLocalDate();
    }
```

You will recognize that in the second case I am using the same conversion as above.

To compare the resulting `LocalDate` variables:

```
    if (localDate1.isEqual(localDate2)) {
        System.out.println("Same date");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Different dates");
    }
```

`LocalDate` also has methods `isBefore` and `isAfter` in case you need to determine which is earlier.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` objects have a method `getTime()` which returns the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan, 1970 ([see the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--)).

So, to compare the two dates:

```
if (d1.getTime() == d2.getTime()) {
    // the dates represent the same point in time
} else {
    // they are different points in time
}
```

You can also use this technique to see if one is before or after the other using `<` or `>`.

**Edit**: If you want to compare the dates regardless of the time component, just divide each value returned from `getTime()` by the number of millis in a day (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24):

```
long millisInADay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
long m1 = d1.getTime() / millisInADay;
long m2 = d2.getTime() / millisInADay;

if (m1 == m2) {
    // the two dates (excluding time) are the same
} else {
    // they're not
}
```

Comment: `getTime()` didn't work gave me two different values `1558742400000` and `1558778400000`

Comment: Edited to remove time factor and only compare date.

Comment: Dividing by the number of milliseconds in a day works correctly only if the asker’s time zone coincides with UTC, which very few time zones do. It’s also very manual and therefore not easy to read.

Comment: [It works incorrectly in your time zone and in mine; this is a link to a live demo](https://ideone.com/RTbDjK) (it’s probaby easiest to read the output first, the code afterwards).

Comment: Thanks for the downvote om my answer. If that was you. It's only a suspicion, I cannot know. It was me downvoiting yours, and I believe I have explained why.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toLocalDate()` from java 8 time to compare date part alone

```
LocalDate localDate1=date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate localDate2=date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
localDate1.compareTo(localDate2)
```

Comment: I got this error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.sql.Date.toInstant(Date.java:304)`

Comment: date  supposed to be util.date bro.Dont know you were using sql.date.

Comment: is both of you're dates are java.sql.date ?? @Youssef

Comment: No they are from `java.util.Date` i don't understand when it come from this `java.sql.Date` maybe cause i am using hibernate ??

Comment: `LocalDate localDate1 = date1 instanceof java.sql.Date ? ((java.sql.Date) date1).toLocalDate() : date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();`. Similarly for `date2` (may in fact be needed for `d2` from the question only).